# Is it possible for a Views Pager Items Count to count the number of field groupings instead of rows?

Tags: views

We have a View that uses grouped entities displayed using an accordion formatter. Each according "group" has a varying amount of rows in it.

We would like to display 10 **groups** per page but if we set the page to display 10 items it may only display one accordion group if that group has 10 or more rows in it.

Is there a way to display a set number of Views grouped fields per page instead of rows?

[image]